# Insert the date and time in any text box from Windows when pressing a keyword shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

how to make a setup to insert the date and time in any text box from Windows when pressing a keyword shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a third-party tool like AutoHotkey to create a script that will insert the current date and time into any text box when you press a keyword shortcut. Here are the steps to create the script:

1. Download and install AutoHotkey from the official website.
2. Right-click on your desktop or in any folder, select "New" and then "AutoHotkey Script". Name the script whatever you like.
3. Right-click on the new script file and select "Edit Script". This will open the script file in your default text editor.
4. Add the following lines of code to the script:

*Copy ruby code:*

```
#z::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

Save and close the script file.

Double-click on the script file to run it. The AutoHotkey icon should appear in the system tray.

Press the Windows key + Z keyboard shortcut to insert the current date and time into any text box that has focus.

In the above script, the keyboard shortcut is set to Windows key + Z. You can modify this to any other key combination by changing the "#z" part of the script. The date and time format can also be modified to your liking by changing the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" part of the script.